# Mac OS X freezes while choosing a keyboard after reset Lion back to the Setup Assistant

Tags: macos

I have a problem with my MacBook Pro, which runs Mac OS X Lion.

I have reset it back to the Setup Assistant.

After I executed the following commands, I need to select the region when I boot; this works fine, but when I choose the keyboard, the whole Mac gets stuck, and I see the loading icon on the screen. Even if I wait one hour, nothing happens.

```
$ mount -uw /
$ rm -R /Library/Preferences/
$ rm -R /Users/username/
$ rm /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/username.plist
$ rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone
```

How can I solve this? I have no Mac OS X disc to reinstall Lion.

Can I create a user via the command line, or skip the setup assistant?

Comment: Was this the only user account on the system?

Comment: yes it was the only one

Comment: Finger in the air tip:  Boot from your recovery drive and perform a permissions fix.  Then try again.

Comment: i dont have a rec. drive

Comment: Even with Lion?  Did you remove it? http://www.apple.com/macosx/recovery/

Comment: ah okay did not know about that. but this did not help me. when i select new installation, it says that this apple id did not buy lion (but i updated it with this apple id). and also i do not have any timemaschiene backup.

Comment: I am not at a Mac, so I can't remember the exact steps, but I was hoping that you could get to the recovery tools like Disk Utility without requiring to attempt a re-install.  I'm curious to know how you installed Lion in the first place if it doesn't like your Apple ID.  Can't help any further right now - sorry

Comment: yes it is possible to get to the recovery tools for me, but there i can't make anything that helps

Comment: I don't think the recovery tools can help you. You need to re-install, and that means buying a copy from the App Store or using the one that came with your hardware. Since Mountain Lion is right around the corner... you probably want to wait until that ships before buying it... maybe you can borrow someone else's Apple ID until then.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bad install. I suggest booting the computer into the hidden Recovery partition by holding <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> at startup and doing an internet recovery system restore. It'll be the second option in the OS X Utilities window that comes up. As long as the iMac is connected to the internet it'll re-download the installer and restore a fresh system to the drive.

If you're trying to bring the MacBook back to the way it was when you purchased it I'd suggest opening the Disk Utility in recovery first and erasing the drive completely. (But only if there's no important data on it!)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I had the same issue on my Mid 2010 MacBook Pro, and I fixed it by holding down shift and booting into safe mode into the setup assistant. It flows smoothly, and before it stopped exactly where you failed at.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I solve this? I have no Mac OS X disc to reinstall Lion.

You don’t need one. [Here’s how you can buy or create a Lion installer USB stick or DVD.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/46943/4408)

Answer (score 0):

It may help to remove the file at `/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist` (this file contains information related to the current time zone). Alternately, you may be able to remove `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist` (which contains keyboard layout settings) to get the setup assistant to complete normally.